# EXCEL: Pull data from one sheet and display on another sheet depending on today()

Tags: excel

I have a series of duplicate sheets inside an excel document called SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY and SATURDAY, with a master sheet called 'Dashboard', on the dashboard I want to display information from the weekdays depending on what date/day of the week it is.

- In cell B6 on each of the weekday sheets is a date
- In cell L1 of each of the weekday sheets is information I want to pull through onto the dashboard
- I need a formula on dashboard to look look at cell b6 in each weekday sheet, and if it matches TODAY() then pull cell L1 value from the matching today's date sheet and display it in a cell on the dashboard

can anyone help? I've got close with IF(OR but not quite there, not sure if I'm going about it the correct way, any help much appreciated!

Thanks,

Sam.

Comment: I'm sure this is possible but this is generally bad data storage practices. Before finishing this, is it possible to challenge the idea that each day needs to be separated by tab? You may be the hero and save yourself a lot time.... It makes more sense to have all the data be on the same sheet with a column that denotes the day. 

Then you can have one dashboard that just needs to be filtered by date (think slicer)

Comment: I agree but unfortunately, the reason for them being separate sheets is because each sheet then feeds into a corresponding report for each day, then the day reports feed into a total weekly report, which also feeds into another utilization report, so there is multiple layers of sheets containing reports which other people use but rely on data from the other sheets. I kept them separate as there's so much data it would be too big to have on one screen. There's atleast 60 rows/coloumns on each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi ok so what you need to do is to is like this. (and I do agree with the other person that you should have all data in one tab reallY=
Create a sheet called admin
in admin a1->B5 write

```
A  B
2  Monday
3  Tuesday
4  Wednesday
5  Thursday
6  Friday
7  Saturday
1  Sunday
```

In any other cell - lets say D1 in that sheet please write

```
=vlookup((weekday(today());a2:b8,2,false)
```

Now go to your "Dashboard tab"

in Cell L1 (or what cell you want to have the data in) you just write

```
=indirect(admin!D1&"!L1")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I used this formula but it has a couple small mistakes, corrected to: 
 =vlookup(weekday(today()),a2:b8,2,false)

Comment: You are right with the ; vs , part by the way - I mix btw english and swedish excel and it confuses a bit